# Unable to open the Eclipse(Oxygen version)

Tags: eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse is not starting at startup, checked the log details and found below the log

```
!SESSION 2017-08-31 13:28:57.167 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:    -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64   -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2017-08-31 13:29:04.253
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2017-08-31 13:29:04.253
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+F11:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F11,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.eclemma.ui.commands.CoverageLast,Coverage Last Launched,
        Coverage Last Launched,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@3a7abd4,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F11,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.command.deliver,Deliver,
        Deliver,
        Category(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.category,Jazz Source Control,Jazz Source Control,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@3846ba32,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2017-08-31 13:29:04.253
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+F12:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F12,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.command.accept,Accept,
        Accept,
        Category(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.category,Jazz Source Control,Jazz Source Control,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@40a32c25,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F12,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.command.searchForTask,Search Repository for Task,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@685280dd,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2017-08-31 13:29:04.253
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+F9:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F9,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.command.checkin,Check-In,
        Check-In,
        Category(com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.category,Jazz Source Control,Jazz Source Control,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@56957f08,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+F9,  
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.command.deactivateAllTasks,Deactivate Task,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@5b0fc8c2,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

gone through some similar questions on internet and found that we have to change bindings of keys(however not sure that it is possible solution) but to do that eclipse should start which is not happening.

**eclipse.ini looks fine.**

*Snapshot of the eclipse hangup at startup..*

[image: Snapshot of the eclipse hangup at startup..]

Comment: Key binding conflicts are just warnings and don't stop Eclipse from starting - something else is going wrong.

Comment: Exactly if I tried to open different work space it is working fine but i guess some issue within work space(unable to find the reason..)

Comment: Issue got resolved. by deleting the contents of the folder **D:\Maximo BOTC Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench**

Comment: Yes, deleting the content of that folder all works for me too. But pay attention because you'll loose all tab opened and some prefereces like prospective selected, some views and so on...

Comment: Yes, thanks. For me, the issue got resolved on deleting the contents by going inside metadata folder. But as mentioned above , it has to be done carefully. In any case after doing this and opening IDE, if the project itself does not show up, it can be imported by clicking on File and Import.

Answer (score 0):

delete the contents of the folder D:\AdiWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).